# Does Rachel Bloom really appreciate Ray Bradbury that much?

Tags: ray-bradbury, rachel-bloom

The [ode to Ray Bradbury by comedian Rachel Bloom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1IxOS4VzKM) was [nominated for a Hugo Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck_Me,_Ray_Bradbury) in 2011. It's quite NSFW, titled "F*ck Me, Ray Bradbury", so I won't include the YouTube video here.

The first two words were probably exaggeration for comedic effect.

But does she really appreciate Ray Bradbury that much, or did she want to honour a great SF writer *in general* and did she choose Bradbury for artistic reasons, such as how his name sounded in the song? (As opposed to "I want to make love, to Asimov").

Comment: [Ray Bradbury watched it](http://geekologie.com/2010/08/heart-attack-ray-bradbury-watc.php).

Comment: A Rachel Bloom tag? Seriously?

Comment: I love [her Bradbury video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1IxOS4VzKM) but has she done anything else that's on topic here?

Comment: @user14111 she _was_ nominated for a Hugo...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rachel Bloom has made clear in several interviews that Ray Bradbury is her favourite writer.

As she said in *[The Dallas Observer](https://www.dallasobserver.com/arts/comedys-not-cute-rachel-bloom-talks-about-being-honest-with-pop-music-and-why-she-likes-ray-bradbury-7084233)*:

> "I was re-reading *The Martian Chronicles* that summer, which is one of my favorite books, (...)"

And in *[Wired](https://www.wired.com/2010/08/rachel-bloom-ray-bradbury/)*:

> "I would say very earnestly that I am overwhelmed with how well he combines such mind-blowingly cool ideas with the realism of how humans deal with these ideas," she told Booktryst. "That's what struck me especially about *Martian Chronicles* or *The Illustrated Man*.... I found myself as emotionally engaged as I was mentally.  If I really met him, I would be nothing but respectful and probably like the 12-year-old boy I secretly am inside."